# Declare Scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a dynamic SQL statement that is failing with the error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@@config"

I have tried to break the code down and can confirm that the following code does return results:

```
Declare @@sql as nvarchar(max);
Declare @SourceDatabase as nvarchar(10);
Declare @DestDatabase as nvarchar(10);
Declare @@Harray as nvarchar(max) ;

Set @SourceDatabase = 'D_EXP_CPM';
Set @DestDatabase = 'T_EXP_CPM';

set @@sql = 'SELECT B.Hierarchy_SKey AS ''NEW'', A.Hierarchy_SKey AS ''OLD''
             INTO ##TEMPHCONVERT
             FROM ' + @SourceDatabase + '.[dbo].[DIM_HIERARCHY] A 
             INNER JOIN ' + @DestDatabase + '.[dbo].[DIM_HIERARCHY] B 
                   ON A.Hierarchy_Desc = B.Hierarchy_Desc
             WHERE A.Hierarchy_SKey in (' + @@Harray + ');'

exec (@@sql);

Declare @@config as NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @@config = COALESCE(@@config + ', H' + cast(A.[NEW] as nvarchar), 'H' + cast(A.[NEW] as nvarchar)) 
FROM ##TEMPHCONVERT A;


Print @@config
```

Which returns the value: "H15, H16, H17, H18"

When this is plugged into the dynamic SQL statement though I get the error...

```
Declare @SourceDatabase as nvarchar(10)
Declare @DestDatabase as nvarchar(10)
Declare @@sql as nvarchar(max) --variable to hold sql statements for this stored proc
Declare @@Harray as nvarchar(max) -- variable to hold hierarchy array elements from source

Set @SourceDatabase = 'D_EXP_CPM';
Set @DestDatabase = 'T_EXP_CPM';

Declare @@config as NVARCHAR(MAX);

set @@sql = 
'SELECT 
B.Hierarchy_SKey AS ''NEW'', A.Hierarchy_SKey AS ''OLD''
INTO ##TEMPHCONVERT
FROM ' + @SourceDatabase + '.[dbo].[DIM_HIERARCHY] A 
INNER JOIN ' + @DestDatabase + '.[dbo].[DIM_HIERARCHY] B 
ON A.Hierarchy_Desc = B.Hierarchy_Desc

WHERE A.Hierarchy_SKey in (' + @@Harray + ');'

exec (@@sql);

set @@sql = '
UPDATE A SET A.[Value_Text] = (SELECT @@config = COALESCE(@@config + '', H'' + cast(A.[NEW] as nvarchar), ''H'' + cast(A.[NEW] as nvarchar)) 
FROM ##TEMPHCONVERT A)
FROM ' + @DestDatabase + '.[dbo].[DIM_CONFIG] A ON A.[Config_Desc] = ''JBCODE FTE Map Hierarchy  List'' ;' 

exec (@@sql);
```

Note I've cut quite a bit of code out of the middle here to make the post as short as possible. Can anybody explain why I'm getting the error?

I've tried declaring the variable inside the dynamic SQL statement in two places but neither allowed the code to run. I'm thinking maybe the variable needs passing somehow but I'm not sure how to do that through to the sub query.

Comment: Why are you declaring variables with a double `@`?  Those are usually system variables.

Comment: naivety as to their use is all.. do you think that is the cause of the issue?

Comment: Don't think @@ is a problem, although it's definitely unconventional :) The "non-dynamic" and dynamic sections of the code execute in different scopes, so when you declare @@config outside, the string has no knowledge of it. Not sure why it's not working when declared inside, possibly as it's never assigned a value? For passing parameters with dynamic sql, look up sp_executesql https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx it's generally better practice, if a bit more fiddly to use, over exec (string).

Comment: I think you are going to have issues at some point with database names being limited to 10 characters. You should also be wrapping those values with QUOTENAME. I would also suggest using temp tables instead of global temp tables. If you create the temp tables inside your procedure they will still be within scope in your dynamic sql. And change the double @ to singles as that just causes confusion.

Comment: @GarethLyons the queries here can't be parameterized but in general I totally agree with your comment.

Comment: Thanks all for the advice I'll look to update the syntax off the back of it once the core issue is resolved. Regards

Comment: @seanlange good point!

Comment: to elaborate, you can't use sp_executesql to dynamically set parts of the object name for a query (server/database/schema/name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the @@config Declaration in the @@sql string:

```
Declare @SourceDatabase as nvarchar(10)
    Declare @DestDatabase as nvarchar(10)
    Declare @@sql as nvarchar(max) --variable to hold sql statements for this stored proc
    Declare @@Harray as nvarchar(max) -- variable to hold hierarchy array elements from source
    Set @SourceDatabase = 'D_EXP_CPM';
    Set @DestDatabase = 'T_EXP_CPM';
set @@sql = 
'SELECT 
B.Hierarchy_SKey AS ''NEW'', A.Hierarchy_SKey AS ''OLD''
INTO ##TEMPHCONVERT
FROM ' + @SourceDatabase + '.[dbo].[DIM_HIERARCHY] A 
INNER JOIN ' + @DestDatabase + '.[dbo].[DIM_HIERARCHY] B 
ON A.Hierarchy_Desc = B.Hierarchy_Desc

WHERE A.Hierarchy_SKey in (' + @@Harray + ');'

exec (@@sql);

set @@sql = 'Declare @@config as NVARCHAR(MAX) 
UPDATE A SET A.[Value_Text] = (SELECT COALESCE(@@config + '', H'' + cast(A.[NEW] as nvarchar), ''H'' + cast(A.[NEW] as nvarchar)) 
FROM ##TEMPHCONVERT A)
FROM ' + @DestDatabase + '.[dbo].[DIM_CONFIG] A ON A.[Config_Desc] = ''JBCODE FTE Map Hierarchy  List'' ;' 
exec (@@sql);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this now gives the error: Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: That is an unrelated additional problem. Substitute the last exec (@@sql) for Print @@sql to study where your dynamic SQL is going wrong.

Comment: I think it should be SELECT COALESCE(@@config + '''', ... Although can you not set the value of config outside the dynamic part? It seems to be a constant as far as I can tell.

Comment: Just noticed your: UPDATE A SET A.[Value_Text] = (SELECT @@config = COALESCE(.. shouldn't be setting @@config, so have amended the code.

Comment: Have used your updated code which gives a further error, but here is the printed statement that it generates:               Declare @@config as NVARCHAR(MAX) 
UPDATE A SET A.[Value_Text] = (SELECT COALESCE(@@config + ', H' + cast(B.[NEW] as nvarchar), 'H' + cast(B.[NEW] as nvarchar)) 
FROM ##TEMPHCONVERT B)
FROM T_EXP_CPM.[dbo].[DIM_CONFIG] A ON A.[Config_Desc] = 'JBCODE FTE Map Hierarchy  List' ;
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'. Not sure why it isn't showing the subquery as a string, but maybe it does that when it executes?

Comment: So the final code that worked involved taking the setting of the config variable outside of the dynamic string ... and now seems to run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are getting the error, but this is a slight rewrite from what you have. Rather than concatenating a long string, I like to declare a template and then replace the parameters before executing. It just makes it more readable to me. I moved all of the related code into @@sql and just return the results in a temp table.

```
Declare @@sql as nvarchar(max);
Declare @SourceDatabase as nvarchar(10);
Declare @DestDatabase as nvarchar(10);
Declare @@Harray as nvarchar(max) ;

Set @SourceDatabase = 'D_EXP_CPM';
Set @DestDatabase = 'T_EXP_CPM';
set @@Harray = '1,2,3';

set @@sql = '
SELECT B.Hierarchy_SKey AS ''NEW'', A.Hierarchy_SKey AS ''OLD''
INTO #TEMPHCONVERT
FROM [[source]].[dbo].[DIM_HIERARCHY] A 
INNER JOIN [[dest]].[dbo].[DIM_HIERARCHY] B 
ON A.Hierarchy_Desc = B.Hierarchy_Desc
WHERE A.Hierarchy_SKey in ([Harray]);

Declare @@config as NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @@config = COALESCE(@@config + '', H'' + cast(A.[NEW] as nvarchar), ''H'' + cast(A.[NEW] as nvarchar)) 
FROM #TEMPHCONVERT A;

select [config] = @@config into ##config
'

set @@sql = replace(@@sql, '[source]', @SourceDatabase)
set @@sql = replace(@@sql, '[dest]', @DestDatabase)
set @@sql = replace(@@sql, '[Harray]', @@Harray)

exec (@@sql);

select * from ##config

drop table ##config
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare @config as NVARCHAR(MAX);

```
SELECT @config = COALESCE(@config + ', H' + cast(A.[NEW] as nvarchar), 'H' + cast(A.[NEW] as nvarchar)) 
FROM #TEMPHCONVERT A;

set @sql = 'UPDATE A SET A.[Value_Text] = (@config )
FROM ' + @DestDatabase + '.[dbo].[DIM_CONFIG] A WHERE A.[Config_Desc] = ''JBCODE FTE Map Hierarchy  List'' ;'


PRINT 'STEP 15 COMPLETE';
```